# Proving that a limit exists almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

> Let $X_{n}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $P(X_n = -1)
>  = P(X_n = 1) = \frac12$.
>
> Prove that: $$X = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} e^{-k} X_{k}$$ exists almost surely.

I'm not so sure how to approach this problem. I am studying for an exam, and I would like to learn how to solve this problem. I have tried to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma by defining a sequence of events and showing that the sum is less than infinity. For example, I know $E[X_{n}] = 0$, so if I can write an expectation as the sum of probabilities, then this sum would go to $0$.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

$|X_k|=1$ almost surely so the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-k} X_k$ is absolutely convergent almost surely.